# verb, idiom or proverb equivalent for bringing two person to fight

Tags: verbs, idioms, proverbs

I am looking for a verb, idiom or proverb that describes a situation that somebody tries to make two parties angry from each other.

I found that mischief-maker means a person who create troubles for others but it doesn't really mean what I am looking for.

Comment: There's "pick a fight", but that's usually on the part of one party.

Comment: @HadiRj "stir up a fight (between two people, etc.)"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[drive a wedge between:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/drive-a-wedge-between)** cause disagreement or hostility between:

*'Clearly, terrorism is about driving a wedge between east and west.'*

Answer (score 2):

**Instigator** is an exceptional word to use.

Cambridge Dictionary Online defines instigator as such:

> A ​person who ​causes something to ​happen, ​especially something ​bad.

(http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/instigator)

Another word you can use is **provoker** and **foment**.

You can see the definitions [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provoke) and [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foment).

Answer (score 2):

The collocation **to sow discord** might work:

> discord: tension or **strife** resulting from a **lack of agreement**; dissension.

([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=discord), [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sow_INF%20discord&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Csow_INF%20discord%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsow%20discord%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsowing%20discord%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsowed%20discord%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsown%20discord%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsows%20discord%3B%2Cc0))

Another old expression comes from the Bible: to **sow strife** or **plant the seeds of strife** (depending on the translation).

> A froward man **soweth strife**: and a whisperer separateth chief friends.

(King James Bible, [Proverbs 16:28](http://biblehub.com/nlt/proverbs/16-28.htm))